# Disable Enter Key

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to disable <kbd>Enter</kbd> key in my JSF page. I am new to JavaScript. If it is possible with JS, 
how can I bind JS and Primefaces components.

Answer (score 1):

All your components have a ID, if it doesn't, create it, it is necessary for JS to know with who he is working with.

Here is a peace of code, it is jQuery:

```
$('#your_element_id').keypress(function(e)
{
   if ( event.which == 13 ) {
     event.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

It will block the `enter` to execute anything.